# Format Text to Number format in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: formatting, reportbuilder3.0

I am working with 4 fields in Report Builder 3.0 in which I am trying to format as a number with the corresponding comma. When I use the number format in the Text Box Properties nothing happens. When I export this report to Excel the field has to be converted to a number as it is being exported as a text field.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can change the formatting in the report itself?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

If I pull data from Oracle using an openquery I get the same issue.  To resolve:

When you have the Text Box Properties box open, select the function key by the Value.
In the expression, add "Int" at the front of the string with () on each side of expression.          (This converts the value of the expression to an integer)

Ex: =Int(Fields!Count.Value)

Close the expression box after making these additions and select "Numbering" in Text Box Properties to format the text box accordingly.